# An extra layer of security for my mongodb - nestjs connection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nestjs

I'm developing a services with NestJS that connects with MongoDB.
I'm going to create a CRUD service where an user at the firs time can register himself as a super-admin. Then, this super-admin will can manage other users (create, delete or modify).

Inside an intranet, everything is okay, but outside, if a random person use that signin service, the applications will be his then.

So my question is: is there another extra security label to manage this situation?

I thought to use database credentials like parameters of the signin form:

```
- username:
- password:
- repeat your password:
- databaseName:
- databasePass:
```

Also, I thought if there is another way using any local certificates  or similar.

Best regards,
Pelayo.

Comment: can you elaborate more how other user get credentials?

Comment: Sure! Super-admin creates other system users with their username and password (each user will can reset his password).

Comment: -Ok, so there are many ways to secure credentials. you can use a hashing and otp-based login system so the user can access their certificates.

Answer (score 1):

When you first time start your server, at that time create one super admin record with some fixed username and password.

These username and password you can store in .env

When super admin first logins, force him to change the password.

Comment: But if I use .env file, new changes won't never be recognized by the server. I would have to restart the service. What do you think?

Comment: You only need to create super admin user when you first time start the server.
After that you don't need to change anything.

Comment: Well, I have been thinking about .env file. I could create a variable called "serial number" and when a new user tries to register himself, he has to type that number to validate the signin process.

Comment: Yes, that is also you can continue with